# How to run exe with Javascript/HTML (Locally)

Tags: javascript, html, word-addins

I need to run the local exe file by using the local Word Add-in which is written in Html+javascript.

**No server, no internet needed. Everything locally**

I tried using:

```
window.open("file:///C:/Windows/notepad.exe"); //results in downloading notepad.exe
```

and

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var commandtoRun = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; 
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
```

Tried also some other examples found on StackOverflow but they also did not work.
I need some solution or workaround on how to run a local exe when the Word Add-in is used.

Comment: With VBScript this is trivial - not so the case with Javascript and you probably need to enable `ActiveX` controls in Windows 8 (?) onwards

Comment: I'd like to make the word add-in public for other users so enabling ActiveX would require work on their end which will cause troubles for sure. Unfortunately can't use VBScript :(

Comment: Can you use VBA from within Word?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, manually yes. Through add-in written in javascript no. I'm working on automation, so everything has to be scripted and I have to do it with a Word add-in as it's one of the requirements